# Remove additional comma from end of string

Tags: sql, scripting

Below command is printing an additional comma at the end of the string. Could you please suggest how to get rid of it.

**Code:**

```
while (stg_columns.next())  
{
    stg_column_list += stg_columns.getColumnValueAsString(1);
    stg_column_list += ","

    stg_column_select_list  += "STG."    + "\"" + stg_columns.getColumnValueAsString(1) + "\","
    stg_column_select_list2 += "NULLIF(" + "\"" + stg_columns.getColumnValueAsString(1) +  "\",''), ";
}
```

**Output:**

```
_key",'')**,** FROM TABLE);
```

Comment: Use `String.Join` instead.

Comment: Hi Dai, I have little knowledge on this, appreciate if you could suggest further on how to use this in my case. stg_columns is list of columns I am capturing and then want them to convert as comma separated string.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a better way to to it, but it will work:

```
let first = true;
while (stg_columns.next()) {
    if(!first)  {
    stg_column_list += ","
    }
    ... 
;}
```

Than you can remove the additional comma at the end of your string